# What's different between getName method and $className?

Tags: extjs

What's different between getName method and $className ?

My example:

```
Ext.define('F.A.C', {name:'sasha',born:'1987'}); 

F.A.C.$className
"F.A.C"

F.A.C.getName();
"F.A.C"
```

Answer (score 2):

The only difference is that $className is a private property you shouldn't access directly. getName is a public getter method you should use.

Answer (score 0):

Actually [`$className`](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.Base-property-S-className) is documented as a (private) **instance property** (although it seems to be acecssible statically), whereas [`getName`](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.Base-static-method-getName) is a (public) **static** function, i.e. it cannot be called from an instance of the class.

```
var instance = new F.A.C();

console.log(instance.$class);
// >> "F.A.C"

console.log(instance.getClass());
// >> TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Comment: Should be using `instance.self.getName()` - every instance has a protected reference to it's constructor / class.